# How to sort associative arrays in descending order?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, reverse

I know about rsort and array_reverse but I'd like to know how you could reverse all elements of an associative array as well as their index numbers. e.g.:

Take
    `$age = array("x"=>"35", "y"=>"45", "z"=>"55");`

and display it as

`z 55`

`y 45`

`x 35`

I tried this but it doesn't show what I want:

```
$age = array("x"=>"35", "y"=>"45", "z"=>"55");
array_reverse($age);
foreach($age as $x => $x_value){
    echo $x . " " . $x_value;
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: [krsort](http://php.net/krsort)

Comment: `$age = array_reverse($age);`  It returns an array it doesn't modify the passed array like the sorts.

Comment: why you use `array_reverse($age);` ?

Comment: You want reverse or descending alphabetical ordering by index?

Comment: You need to edit your question and make it clear.  If you reverse `c,a,t` you get `t,a,c`.  If you sort it descending you get `t,c,a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to sort by key in decending order so you need to do flowing.Because `array_reverse()` function swap key with value in an array.

```
$age = array("x"=>"35", "y"=>"45", "z"=>"55");
krsort($age);
foreach($age as $x => $x_value){
 echo $x . " " . $x_value;
echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: _reverse all elements of an associative array as well as their index numbers_